# How to create top navigation in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am working on app and I am new to React Native . Actually I want to create top navigator, I will provide an image which I want to achieve  ( I don't know what we will say for it it may be top navigator or something else but please have a look to an image and I want to achieve same as mentioned in image ) .

Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<View>` components and `display:flex`.

Put your items on image in `<View>` and set positions using `justifyContent,alignItems and position` properties.

At end you can set background image using `<BackgroundImage>` component.

Comment: do we need built in component for it or we will achieve it through custom component ?

Comment: built in components are enough

Comment: No, I mean do we need top navigator which we are extracting from `react-native` lib

Comment: no you don't need but can use top navigator from other libraries too.